# Past due Time-based workflow with criteria set from other workflows

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow, order-of-execution, executioncontext

I have a very unique condition happening during a time based workflow that is causing some unexpected behavior. I am curious to know if anyone has had a similar experience and if I am correct in understanding what is happening here.

We have a 3 time based workflows that cause 3 different time-based actions to be performed based on 3 different date fields on the same object. Each action is set to go off 50 days after each workflows respective date field. For example: **Workflow 1** performs action 1 50 days after **date 1**, **workflow 2** performs action 2 50 days after **date 2**, and **workflow 3** performs action 3 50 days after **date 3**. Records are routed to workflow 1 by default but if a submitted date field is filled then workflow 2 is suppose to fire. This submitted date is filled in by another workflow. This is the setup of the workflows.

The problem is that when my submitted date is filled out the workflow 1 rule seems to not understand that this is the case - **only** when the date 1 field is already past the 50 day time frame. This situation only happens when a record has already exceeded the day time and the workflow 1 is executed within 5 minutes of being editted by a user. **This operates as expected if the submitted date is not populated in the same edit session as meeting the criteria for workflow 1.** RECAP: So a record is getting assigned a submission date and is also found to match the criteria of workflow 1. If these happen in the same context the record should fall under workflow 2 but the workflow 1 criteria seems to be met instead of workflow 2 critera.

What I think it is:

My guess at the situation is that time-based workflows are put into a queue that determines when they need to be executed. When my record was evaluated - the workflow assigning the submission date had not ran and it met the criteria for workflow 1. The system determined that the record was past due and should have executed X number of days ago at the 50 day mark relative to its date field. It is then put into a job that tells the workflow to run as soon as resources are available (this is why the action happens 5 minutes after). After this action takes place the submission date was populated by another workflow processed after the time-based workflow's criteria but in the same execution context. This forces the object to meet the workflow 2 criteria but because the record was set to execute immediately the action of taking the record out of the time-based workflow is not performed and the workflow 1's action is performed instead of workflow 2.

I feel like I did a poor job of explaning this so if it does not make sense let me know and I will attempt to clarify what I can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is desired behavior that if submitted date is filled workflow 1 should NOT fire and workflow 2 should?  Does wf1 include a criteria that submitted date is blank?  You are correct in how time based rules evaluate - they are put in the queue.  When the date is in the past, then the rule fires within 15 mins or so.  Not fully following the expected behavior and the error but will try to help!